# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\test\functions.php on line 72

Tags: php, pdo

I trying to run my query but everytime I try to run it, it would give me this kind of error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object.

this is my code:

**Single.php:**

```
<?php
require 'admin/config.php';
require 'functions.php';

$conexion = conexion($db_config);
$url_canal = url_canal($_GET['url']);

if (!$conexion) {
    header('Location: error.php');
}

if (empty($url_canal)) {
    header('Location: index.php');
}

$canal = obtener_canal_por_url($url_canal, $conexion);

if(!$canal) {
    header('Location: index.php');
}

$canal = $canal[0];

require 'views/single.view.php';

?>
```

**functions.php:**

```
function limpiarDatos($datos) {
    $datos = trim($datos);
    $datos = stripslashes($datos);
    $datos = htmlspecialchars($datos);
    return $datos;
}
function url_canal($url) {
    return limpiarDatos($url);
}

function obtener_canal_por_url($url, $conexion) {
    $resultado = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM canales WHERE url = $url LIMIT 1");
    $resultado = $resultado->fetchAll();
    return ($resultado) ? $resultado : false;
}
```

Can you help me to solve this, please? i want to know where is my mistake. Thank you

**Conexion:**

```
function conexion($db_config) {
try {
    $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='. $db_config['bd'], $db_config['usuario'], $db_config['pass']);
    return $conexion;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: can you share the code of conexion function

Comment: Your query is likely susceptible to SQL injection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: im go to check that, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your query with

```
$resultado = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM canales WHERE url = '$url' LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your query (I guess url is a string):

```
$resultado = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM canales WHERE url = '" . $url . "' LIMIT 1");
```

Then check `$resultado` before `fetchAll()`:

```
if ($resultado) {
    $rows = $resultado->fetchAll();
}
```